# Pyspark dataframe withColumn 'when' not working with '<' or '>'

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to create a new column in the same dataframe with certain greater than or less than conditions using 'when, like the following:

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "new_col",
    when(col("age") < 17, 1234) #when(col("DAYS") < 30, lit("ECONOMICAL"))
    .when(col("age") > 17, 5678)
    .otherwise(df.old_col)
```

However, I am getting this error message:
'<' not supported between instances of 'Row' and 'int'

I've tried this `when(int(col("age")) < 17, 1234)`
and it didn't work.

I also tried using '<=' and '>=' and they also didn't work

I even saw another post in here suggesting a user a solution containing `when(col("DAYS") < 30, lit("ECONOMICAL"))` in a withColumn like mine, but I tried doing the `lit` in the result too and no good.

Does anyone know why this can't be done? I have no problems doing an == between rows and int, the problem is just when I try '<' and '>'?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: better create minimal working code with example values directly in code - so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: maybe write normal function and use `.apply()`

Comment: what is `col()` ?

Comment: Do you happen to use `col` parameters or define a function with name `col`?  the error suggests that `col('age')` is returning Row object which is not the original functionality of `col` from `pyspark.sql.functions`.  try `print(col('age'))`.

Comment: this is what I get from the print: Column<'age'>

Comment: Hmm, that seems right.  could you post (in the question) some sample lines of the `df.show()` just before this line?

Comment: Found the issue, I had to add a .cast(int) to the col, for some reason in other dataframes it wasn't an issue but in this one it was, maybe it came in a different format

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - was need to add explicit casting...

```
df = df.withColumn(
    "new_col",
    when(col("age").cast("int") < 17, 1234)
    .when(col("age").cast("int") > 17, 5678)
    .otherwise(df.old_col)
```

This solution worked.

Comment: better don't put `**` in code because someone may try to use this answer literally with `**` ;)